# Excel 2003 lag under Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel-2003

I'm running Excel 2003 under Windows 7 64-bit.  Even on a blank spreadsheet, Excel 2003 will lag or freeze up every 10 seconds or so and every time I insert a value in the spreadsheet.  I have attempted to turn on manual calculations.  What else could be causing this slow down and how can I diagnose this annoying bug?

Comment: Do you have any plug-ins?  If so, try disabling them.  Also, try doing an Office repair (Help > Detect & Repair).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steve above was correct, but he did not leave an answer, only a comment.  It was a plug-ins related problem.  When I disabled all non-essential plugins, Excel no longer lagged.

Answer (score 1):

Slow Excel 2003 solved - I found the default printer driver set in Windows causes slow file opening. I made another printer the default windows printer and excel 2003 opens straight away.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Office 2003 (including Excel) and I haven't had a slow down of any sort. The only thing that I could think of is that you may have something (a virus perhaps?) running in the background. Have you checked your task manager while it's running?

Comment: Why do people always mention viruses and slow-downs in the same sentence? Yes, some viruses can cause a slowing of the system, but compared to other reasons, a virus is hardly the first thing I would mention...

Comment: The slow down only seems to occur with Excel, not any other, even computationally intensive, programs.  In this case, I have scanned the process list and none correspond to any known viruses, and my virus scanner hasn't reported anything. @neurolysis, while I agree it is an often mentioned cause of lag, viruses/malware are often overlooked as the cause since their presence is not immediately obvious.